# Extraneous input '0' expecting ']'

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I encountered the following error: Extraneous input '0' expecting ']'

Please tell me where I went wrong and how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Count EMA Crossovers", overlay=false)

emas = array.new_float(5)
emas[0] := ta.ema(close, 7)
emas[1] := ta.ema(close, 20)
emas[2] := ta.ema(close, 50)
emas[3] := ta.ema(close, 100)
emas[4] := ta.ema(close, 200)

pairs = array.new_float(10, 2)
idx = 0
for i = 0 to 3
    for j = i + 1 to 4
        pairs[idx][0] := emas[i]
        pairs[idx][1] := emas[j]
        idx += 1

count = 0
for pair in pairs
    if pair[1] > pair[0]
        count += 1

plot(count, title="Count Cross", color=color.blue, style=plot.style_histogram)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pinescript you can't address array like in python.

You must use 'array' (if 1 dimensions) and 'matrix' (if 2 dimensions) to do that.

Please refer to :  https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Arrays.html.

Your code could look something like this :

```
//@version=5
indicator("Count EMA Crossovers", overlay=false)

emas = array.new_float(5)
array.set(emas, 0, ta.ema(close, 7))
array.set(emas, 1, ta.ema(close, 20))
array.set(emas, 2, ta.ema(close, 50))
array.set(emas, 3, ta.ema(close, 100))
array.set(emas, 4, ta.ema(close, 200))

pairs = matrix.new<float>(10,2)
idx = 0
for i = 0 to 3
    for j = i + 1 to 4
        matrix.set(pairs, idx, 0,  array.get(emas, j))
        matrix.set(pairs, idx, 1,  array.get(emas, j))
        idx += 1

count = 0
for i = 0 to 9
    if matrix.get(pairs, i,1) > matrix.get(pairs, i, 0)
        count += 1

plot(count, title="Count Cross", color=color.blue, style=plot.style_histogram)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me. However I applied your code and it doesn't work, 'count' is always 0. I apologize for my stupidity, but can you teach me more? Sincerely thank you.

Comment: I think I found the problem, we have 2 lines 'array.get(emas, i)', just change the line below to 'array.get(emas, j)'. The code worked, thank you very much.